# How to get a byte[] object from another class object in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, arrays

I know that in **J2ME** I can get a `byte[]` object from a String object by using the `getBytes()` method. My question is : is it possible to get a `byte[]` object from any other `class type` ? In addition : is it possible to get a `byte[]` object from a user-defined class object ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to get a byte[] object from any other class type ?

Some classes may implement a simular service.

> Is it possible to get a byte[] object from a user-defined class object ?

Not without you writing the conversion yourself.

---

Example how to do it yourself *(just note that the `DataOutputStream` handles the conversion, for example which byte order that is used)*:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
{
    // conversion from "yourObject" to byte[]
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOuputStream(out);
    dos.writeInt(yourObject.intProperty);
    dos.writeByte(yourObject.byteProperty);
    dos.writeFloat(yourObject.floatProperty);
    dos.writeChars(yourObject.stringProperty);
    dos.close();
}
byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Also, none of this is J2ME-specific... Plain old java all the way.

Comment: @Romain well, code example added in rev 2 certainly introduced _some_ J2ME specific. For example [dos.writeFloat](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeFloat(float) "MIDP / CLDC API documentation") won't compile in Java ME CLDC version 1.0 (JSR 30)

Comment: @gnat I meant not J2ME-specific as in there is no "generic" way to turn a random class instance into a `byte[]`. Now if J2ME-specific classes provides high-level helpers do to so, it's a different question, kind of like "Library X does it".